# Retornar Dados de Função JSON e Preencher DIV

Tags: angularjs

Quero aprender a recuperar os dados de uma função que faz um GET numa API e me retorna o JSON. Quero recuperar os dados e preencher uma lista... com o `ng-repeat`.

Está acontecendo de vir **undefined** e depois nem sei o que colocar no `ng-repeat`.

### Angular JS

```
/* Factory */
App.factory('dealerFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
   var factory = {
      obterDados: _obterDados
   }

   // Lista de Concessionárias
   function _obterDados() {
      $http.get("http://localhost:8888/dealers").then(
         function(response){
            return response.data;
         }
      );
   }

   return factory;
}]);

App.controller('ListaCtrl', ['$scope', 'dealerFactory', function($scope, dealerFactory){

   $scope.dealers = [];
   $scope.dealers = dealerFactory.obterDados();

}]);
```

### HTML

```
<ion-content ng-controller="ListaCtrl">
   <ion-list>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="{{ result in dealers }}" id="{{result.id}}">
         <h3>{{result.dealer}}</h3>
         <h4>{{result.stars}}</h4>
      </ion-item>
   </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Atualização:

Quando faço o código abaixo só para motivos de debug, me retorna undefined. A URL está certa, está trazendo o jSON. Eu testei o LINK no navegador e também dei `console.log` no return da função e trouxe-me os dados.

```
$scope.dealers = [];
$scope.dealers = dealerFactory.obterDados();
console.log($scope.dealers);
```

Acredito que seja algo relacionado a Assíncronização. A variável ainda não sofreu alterações e o **return** é executado primeiro...
Não sei como resolver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, primeiramente crie a variável no escopo do angular,

```
App.controller('ListaCtrl', ['$scope', 'dealerFactory', 
 function($scope,    dealerFactory){

$scope.dealers = [];
$scope.dealers = dealerFactory.obterDados();

// não precisa fazer mais nada
}]);
```

HTML

```
<ion-content ng-controller="ListaCtrl">
//correção nova aqui
 <ion-list ng-repeat="dealer in dealers">
   <ion-item id="{{dealer.id}}">
      <h3>{{dealer.dealer}}</h3>
      <h4>{{dealer.stars}}</h4>
   </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

CORREÇÃO:

```
 App.factory('dealerFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
   var factory = {
    obterDados: _obterDados
   }

function _obterDados() {
   $http.get("http://localhost:8888/dealers/1").then(
     function(data){
//como voce usou o then e não o sucess o data que tem o json esta dentro de
//data.data e não somente data
//se voce usa o .sucess ao invés do .then, usa apenas data no retorno
        return data.data;
      }
   );
 }

   return factory;
}]);
```

Acredito que isto resolve seu problema, agora precisa ver se sua API esta realmente retornando os dados, pois você disse que as vezes retorna undefined, talvez a API esteja com algum problema.

Qualquer coisa me avise por gentileza,

Espero ter ajudado

Abraços!

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou sim. Está vindo vazia e não dá nenhum erro no código. Eu baixei um plugin do Chrome que esconde o erro de Allow Control Access Origin... É assim... eu uso o Ionic Server na porta 8100 e o Apigility na porta 8888. Então é como se fosse outro domínio... e dá erro nesse Header.

Comment: Esta usando o CORS no seu Ionic Server? Porque eu tive problemas também usando Ionic em no localhost e minha API em outro domínio, tive que implementar em meu back-end um tratamento pra aceitar qualquer origem, pelo menos enquanto estava na fase de desenvolvimento

Comment: Não estou, não sei configurar isso. Além do que estou utilizando o Apigility para construir API's.

Comment: Mas agora parou de dar o erro. Está dando esse: `[$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'in' is an unexpected token at column 8 of the expression [dealer in dealers] starting at [in dealers]`

Comment: Arrumei o código, verifique agora, no {{dealers in dealer}} não tem a interpolação... é apenas aspas duplas

Comment: Ah entendi. Agora realmente parou o erro. Estou pegando as manhas, mas o voltou o erro do Allow... vou pesquisar como faz pra corrigir.

Comment: @Zoom veja neste link https://apigility.org/documentation/recipes/allowing-request-from-other-domains tem uma boa explicação de como aceitar requisições de outras origens no Apigility

Comment: Estou fazendo exatamente isso. Hehe' Está instalando...

Comment: Pronto. Configurei, mas está dando CONNECTION REFUSED. Lá tem uns parâmetros, acho que não sei preencher. Vou editar a pergunta e postar.

Comment: Cara, consegui configurar. Agora o problema é que não está listando. Aparece isso no HTML `<!-- ngRepeat: dealer in dealers -->`

Comment: Atualizei a minha pergunta.

Comment: Consegue entender minha pergunta ?